# ¿Como ejecutar un método tras otro en Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, sintaxis

Pues resulta que quiero escribir código mucho más organizado, rápido y fácil de comprender para mis propios paquetes y módulos. He visto que algunas librerías como Selenium hacen una ejecución de código similar a este ejemplo:

```
objeto.funcion1().funcion2()
```

Es decir en Selenium sería así un ejemplo:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("tu_xpath_aqui").click()
```

Entonces cómo podemos observar es como si se ejecutarán métodos uno tras otro. Y la verdad eso es hermoso, y pues he buscado como hacer eso y no consigo una forma. En mis cursos que tome de programación en Udemy e incluso en otros ejemplos de tutoriales de YouTube jamás ví algo igual. Y la verdad que uno lo usa así y ni se da cuenta, pero cuando me di cuenta que sería útil de hacer, no sé cómo se hace. Si es posible una referencia que explique cómo hacerlo, o que me expliquen aquí sería útil.

Comment: ejjee estaras encantado con el paquete `pandas`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A esta técnica se le conoce como [encadanamiento de métodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). La forma de obtener este comportamiento es simplemente retornando el propio objeto.

```py
class A:
    def saludar(self):
        print('Hola')
        return self

    def despedir(self):
        print('Adios')
        return self

a = A()
a.saludar().despedir()
```

Depediendo de tu necesidades el objeto retornado puede ser distinto al original pero la idea de encadenamiento generalmente es aplicada sobre un mismo objeto.

Answer (score 5):

Primero voy a explicar **la diferencia entre métodos y funciones**. Son muy parecidos pero te voy a explicar las diferencias

**Funciones:** es lo que se conoce como un "callable" es decir una pieza de código que puede ser llamada de manera independiente. Un ejemplo de función es:

```
def suma(a,b):
    return a+b

print(suma(4,5))
```

**Métodos:** es una pieza de código que está asocidada a un objeto y puede operar con los datos que son contenidos en la clase. Un ejemplo de método es:

```
#Creamos la clase
class Numero:
    def __init__(self, a,):
        self.a = a

    def suma(self, x):
        self.a = self.a + x 
        return self

    def resta(self, x):
        self.a = self.a - x
        return self

    def consultar_numero(self):
        return self.a

#Instanciamos la clase y tenemos un objeto
objeto_numero = Numero(10)

#Hacemos todas las operaciones que queramos encadenadas mientras devolvamos el objeto
objeto_numero.suma(2).resta(10).suma(1).suma(2).resta(5).consultar_numero()
```

Esto se consigue retornando el propio objeto en los métodos y es muy utilizado en muchas de las librerías de Python. Como puedes ver la sintaxis (habitualmente) es distinta entre una función y un método.

Lo que está sucediendo en el ejemplo, es que como **los datos están contenidos dentro de la clase (esta es la clave)**. Tu le puedes ir pasando distintos métodos, ya que el resultado se va "guardando" y se van ejecutando las operaciones de forma encadenada. La primera operación de la cadena devuelve el objeto, este objeto es cogido por la segunda operación y devuelto, el cual es cogido por la tercera y devuelto, etc...

Por supuesto el método *consultar_numero()* nunca se podrá encadenar puesto que devuelve un número entero que es *a*

### Respondiendo a tu pregunta

Los métodos se pueden encadenar si la clase ha sido programada para ello, por eso habrá veces que lo podrás hacer y otras que no. En este caso la clase  `webdriver()` de *Selenium* ha sido creada con ese proposito, de tal forma que cuando instancias esa **clase**, se va devolviendo el objeto para que tu puedas seguirle pasando los métodos definidos en dicha clase.

Comment: Hola. Si se diferencias entre metodos de clase POO y funciones. A mi no me gusta programar en estructurado siempre manejo POO ya que yo escribo mucho codigo, paquetes etc... Ya le di a tu respuesta como correcta. Entonces todo era simple, es que no sabia que se podia llamar un metodo tras otro de un objeto como acabaste de mostrarme. Muchas gracias te agradezco.

Comment: Perdona, quise diferenciar ambas cosas al principio y pensé que tu confusión tal vez podía venir de ahí!, edito la pregunta para quitar esa parte :) . Y de nada siempre es un gusto ayudar!

Comment: También muy interesantes las respuestas de Sergio Cortez y @eftshift0 en las cuales se añade un link de wikipedia y se expresa que se puede combinar con distintaos objetos! Sin duda merecen también un voto positivo :)

Answer (score 2):

Sin sentarme a analizar con mucha profundidad, eso se puede hacer si en las funciones devuelves *objetos*.

Digamos, algo como esto (perdón si pelo algo en la sintaxis de python):

```
class A:

    def someMethod(self):
        return "Hello"

class B:

    def anA(self):
        return A() # creamos una instancia de A

b = B()
print(b.anA().someMethod())
```

Y con eso deberíamos ver `Hello` en la salida